# Which driver should I use for my GeForce4 MX 440 on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I have an old computer with an nVidia GeForce4 MX 440 graphics card.

On Fedora 20 I have a selection of three nVidia drivers from the [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) repos:

- `kmod-nvidia`
- `kmod-nvidia-173xx`
- `kmod-nvidia-304xx`

I'd use the akmod packages, but that's beside the point. So, for this old graphics card, which driver should I use? Or should I stick with the nouveau drivers?

Answer (score 2):

The [nVidia howto](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) from RPM Fusion says:

> **GeForce 2 through GeForce 4**
>
> Supported up to Fedora 14 - EOL, no more nvidia updates
>
> ```
> yum install akmod-nvidia-96xx "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
> yum update -y
> ```

["What's a legacy driver?"](http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html) from the nVidia website says:

> The 96.43.xx driver supports the following set of GPUs:
>
> Note: Support for the 96.43.xx series is discontinued. No further releases from this series are planned.
>
> ```
> NVIDIA chip name              Device PCI ID
> GeForce4 MX 440               0x0171
> GeForce4 MX 440 with AGP8X    0x0181
> ```

Your video card is a GeForce 4 and you're running Fedora 20, so it looks like your only option is the **nouveau** driver.

Comment: Can I use one of the newer drivers with the old graphics card, perhaps? Nouveau seems to ne somewhat of a catch-all for old adapters...

Comment: What do you mean? The set of drivers is split between generations and because your video card is from an old generation, nVidia doesn't support it anymore. Except perhaps some issues and less speed for 3D acceleration, the **nouveau** driver is a good alternative.

Comment: @polemon, is my answer still not clear enough?